# Условие для созданного столбца в выборке

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Составить список покупателей, сделавших более 2 заказов. Результат отсортировать в алфавитном порядке фамилий покупателей. Проблема тут "COUNT(*) AS buyersShopping" и тут "buyersShopping > 2".

```
SELECT Orders.personalNumberBuyer, Buyers.name, COUNT(*) AS buyersShopping FROM Orders, Buyers
WHERE Buyers.personalNumber = Orders.personalNumberBuyer AND buyersShopping > 2 /* Что-то в этом духе */
GROUP BY Orders.personalNumberBuyer, Buyers.name
ORDER BY Buyers.name ASC
```

[image: Результат без проверки на кол-во]
[image: Диаграмма базы]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Orders.personalNumberBuyer, Buyers.name, COUNT(*) AS buyersShopping
FROM Orders, Buyers
WHERE Buyers.personalNumber = Orders.personalNumberBuyer
GROUP BY Orders.personalNumberBuyer, Buyers.name
having COUNT(*) > 2
ORDER BY Buyers.name ASC
```

[Having](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_having_clause.html)